# Vue.js and javascript wont work

Tags: vue.js

I have a problem with javascript and vue.js, it should be simple but it's not, and I don't understand why I can't set a height to the element with javascript.  Here is an error I get after I try to change the height - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

```
<template>
<div class="Icontent" id="Icontent" v-bind:mode="this.mode">Content {{this.mode}} </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      name: "Icontent",
      props:['mode'],
      created:function(){
          created(this);
      },
      data:function(){
        return{
           mode:this.mode
        }
      }
    }

    function created(component){
        //document.getElementsByClassName('Icontent').style.height = 100;
        //document.getElementById('Icontent').setAttribute("style","height:" + 100);

    }
</script>

<style scoped>
.Icontent{
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 2px #09f;
}

.Icontent[mode="mobile"]{
  top: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Use `mounted` instead of `created` and generally don't select elements in JavaScript. You should change the state (`data`) and use then the state directly in the template. In the case of styling, you can add a class with the attribute `:class=""`. Then, style elements with such a class differently.

Comment: You can find the detailed lifecycle diagram of Vue in the documentation. The template is not yet rendered after `created`, but only after `mounted`: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't name the `created` function the same as the vuejs `lifecycle function`.
2. No need to declare it outside of your export, place it in `methods`, like this:

   `methods: {
       init: function() {
           //code goes here
       }
   }`
3. `document.getElementsByClassName` does not return an instance of a node and therefore you can't set the style this way. You would have to loop all elements first.
4. You could just define the `style` as an object in your `data` function and bind it to the element with `:style="someStyleObject"`
5. You can't define `mode` in `data` if it's also a property.
6. Check your console, you're going to have errors.

Comment: Thanks for replay
1.I am not sure what is a lifecycle yet
2.Got it
3.This is was my question, why it won't work? I don't want to do loops, i want to change the height.
4.Got it
5.Got it
6.My console always RED :))))

Comment: @VadimKorolov Have a [look here for the vuejs lifecycle hooks](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks). 3. Because the selector is wrong and you have other errors preventing the code from executing in the first place. You can use the `document.getElementById` and it will work once you've solved the other problems.

Comment: I think I got it what is a lifecycle, I have to use a "mounted" function to get the DOM element, Thanks!